# How to get MDX openingperiod() to work as calculated measure in ssas cube

Tags: visual-studio, ssas, mdx, cube

I want to use the MDX functions openingperiod() and closingperiod() in our cube, but cannot get it to work properly.

Is this actually possible, or are these functions only applicable in a MDX-query?

The main two articles I used to learn about openingperiod() are: 
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/stairway-to-mdx-level-12-mdx-timedate-series-functions-openingperiod-and-closingperiod-functions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/openingperiod-mdx?view=sql-server-2017

In the above documentation the two functions openingperiod() and closingperiod() are only used in a query, but I want to integrate them in the cube.

The code I used as a regular query is:

```
sum(
openingperiod
    (
    [Date Booking].[Year Month],
    [Date Booking].[Year Month].currentmember
    ),
    [Measures].[Goods Amount])
```

The result should be the amount of goods at the start of the month, but the result is `NULL`.

I used `sum` to get a valid syntax that points to the right member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to give you the idea from Adventure Works sample database.

This should be the syntax to create your calculated member in the cube ([Adventure Works] is the cube name in this example), so you can call it later:

```
create member [Adventure Works].Measures.MyMeasure4
as
(OpeningPeriod([Date].[Calendar].[Date],[Date].[Calendar].Currentmember.Parent), [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
```

And then you should call it like this to see the result:

```
select {Measures.MyMeasure4, [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} on 0,
[Date].[Calendar].members on 1
from [Adventure Works]
```

So for January, MyMeasure4 will have the value of January the 1st member (value for opening period), for February it will have the value from Feb the 1st, if that was your intention.

Comment: It seems likes it is working, but I get errors returned where I would have expected a value. Does ```[Date Booking].[Year Month]``` needs to be numeric? It is now e.g. 2019 - jan

Comment: No. The first argument of OpeningPeriod function is Level, so [Date Booking].[Year Month] should be level name in your cube, you should check that first. It should go like this: OpeningPeriod([DimensionName].[HierarchyName].[LevelName], [DimensionName].[HierarchyName].CurrentMember)

Comment: The error is gone, but the null values that come in place do give the desired outcome either. Still working on it, but MDX is a new language for me so it takes some time.

Comment: I think you gave the right answer, all other documentation and fora say the same. It still does not work for me and I have come to the believe that there must be some problem with fields in the cube.